# Remove myself from an agentset in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

This is quite a simple problem but I don't know why I can't solve it, nor do my searches on the Net are suitable to my code. I've been stuck for weeks because of this simple problem  ・゜・(ノД`)
.

Here is the problem,

I have an agentset called `myteamset` where in this agentset, it include myself and 2 other turtles, what I need now is to remove myself from this set and name this new agentset as `myteamset1`

I have tried 
`set myteamset1 myteamset [not member? self myself]`  - got error;
`set myteamset1 myteamset with [self != myself]` - didn't get error but the agentset is empty

Code:
    `ask turtles [
        if myteamset = nobody [
          let possible-teammates other turtles with [ myteamset = nobody ]
          ifelse count possible-teammates > 1 [
            set myteamset (turtle-set self n-of 2 possible-teammates )
           ; set myteamset1 myteamset [not member? self myself] here is problem`

Please help me, I don't know why I can't do this simple code, it's like my brain stuck and I feel so desperate now, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `set myteamset1 other myteamset`. The primitive `other` means everyone in the agentset except me.

Here is a full example

```
turtles-own [myteamset myteamset1]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  ask turtles
  [ set myteamset (turtle-set self n-of 2 turtles)
    set myteamset1 other myteamset
  ]
end
```

Comment: How can I see the other agent? **from this code, I can't get the agentset list without myself, as it includes myself in the list, can you see what's wrong? thanks for the help.** Here is my code, 
`set myID who` `set myteamset1 other myteamset`
        `set teammmembers1 myteamset1`
       `let ids1 sort [myID] of myteamset1`
        `ask myteamset1 `
          `[set teammatesID2 ids1
          `set myteamset1 teammmembers1]`

Comment: See revised answer. There is no need to have `who` numbers, just stay with the agentsets.

Comment: Is there a primitive like 'other' that works similarly but than for myself?

Comment: @DeMelkbroer no, but there's no problem with removing specific agents with something like `set myteamset1 teamset with [not member? self exclude-set]`. Note that `myself` is actually a keyword in NetLogo that means something other than how it is used in the question title.